# ColdFusion Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

Is it possible to write JavaScript Validation for ColdFusion Inputs and Selects?

**My desired Outcome**
(I have this piece that works perfect with Inputs but I have ColdFusion select statements (that are includes) and this script for validation just skips over them.. Is there anyway to call out ColdFusion Inputs and Selects making them required and not required depending on a Yes/No radio button?)

http://jsfiddle.net/0kaxb6qt/

```
$('#div1 input').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('required'); 
});

function showhideForm(Mailto_1) {
        if (Mailto_1 == "Yes") {
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'none';
            $('#div1 input').not('#cmiddlename_1').not('#cm2street_1').each(function() {
                //console.log('wat');
                $(this).attr('required', 'required');
            });
        } else if (Mailto_1 == "No") {
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
            $('#div1 input').each(function() {
                $(this).removeAttr('required');
            });
            $("#div1 > .clearfix input:text").val("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: We need to see at least some of the HTML generated by the includes. I assume you mean you are using `cfselect`? If so, I would recommend using plain `select` boxes. The ColdFusion UI components are poorly implemented, way out of date and have limited functionality.

Comment: alternatively, the included cf code would be useful.  Until then, the only answer to your question is, "yes".

Comment: If you're using CFINPUT, CFSELECT, etc., the end result is HTML. Just make sure the final HTML is output with the correct IDs or NAMEs and your code should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can grab the id and set required to either true or false:

```
$('#cmiddlename_1').prop('required',true);
$('#cm2street_1').prop('required',false);
```

Basically turning them off and on.